# Narrowing down collection prior to Mongo text search

Tags: mongodb, meteor, full-text-search, simple-schema

I have a collection that is a simpleschema that looks somewhat like this

```
VendorCategories = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Category"
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        label: "Slug"
    }
});

VendorsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    vendorName: {
        type: String,
        label: "Vendor Name",
        min: 3,
    },
    vendorCategory: {
        type: VendorCategories,
    },
    vendorDescription: {
        type: String,
        label: "Vendor Description",
        min: 45,
    },
});
```

I have a mongo index setup for this collection like so.

```
Vendors._ensureIndex({
  'vendorName': 'text',
  'vendorDescription': 'text',
  'VendorCategories.name': 'text',
});
```

Currently this is what my publication to search thru this index using Mongo Text Search https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/text/ looks like

```
Meteor.publish('searchVendors', function(query) {
    if (query) {
        return Vendors.find({
            $text: {
                $search: query
            }
        }, {
            fields: {
                score: {
                    $meta: 'textScore'
                }
            },
            sort: {
                score: {
                    $meta: 'textScore'
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        return Vendors.find();
    }
});
```

And my helper method looks something like this.

```
vendorSearchResults: function() {
    var category = FlowRouter.getQueryParam("category");//narrow by this first
    var terms = FlowRouter.getQueryParam("terms");

    Meteor.subscribe("searchVendors", terms);
    if (terms) {
        return Vendors.find({}, { sort: [["score", "desc"]] });
    } else {
        return Vendors.find({});
    }
}
```

Currently this returns the search for all **var terms** that match the vendor name and description. But what I want to achieve is first have the  collection results be narrowed down to the **vendorCategories.name** before the *vendorName* and *vendorDescription* gets searched.

Any help with this would much appreciated, Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you tried an index with your desired order?

Comment: @DaveCoast don't think I have, all my code is up there. Could you perhaps show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator can be combined with other match criteria:

```
    return Vendors.find({
        "VendorCategories.name": "Acme Corporation",
        $text: {
            $search: query
        }
    },
```